# What are those lights close ahead of Luke's X-34 landspeeder?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the original movie *A New Hope* (1977), in the scene where the Tusken raiders try to shoot Luke's X-34 landspeeder, if you have sharp eyes or do stop-play slowly, you can see two circular bright lights close ahead of the landspeeder and a third bright spot. Even though those lights were removed in further editions of the movie, I have been trying to discover the origin of them. To me they don’t appear to be an error but probably the glare from headlights (originally conceived by SoroSuub) or the reflection of Taooine's two suns in the Duraplex windscreen but I haven't found any reference of those lights in the Canon/Legend, thus, what are those lights ahead of the X-34 landspeeder?

[image: Still_image_from_A_New_Hope_1]

[image: Still_image_from_A_New_Hope_2]

Comment: Are you sure that's not reflection off the speeder itself?

Comment: @DavidW - It could be, and also, it could be a reflection of C-3PO and the speeder. I made a question related to the scene showing a picture of the speeder prop used. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223907/what-made-the-tusken-raiders-unable-unwilling-to-shoot-down-lukes-landspeeder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just speeder itself, no lights:

[image]

Comment: OP states that they are only visible in the original cut of the film, not Special Edition. Is this clip from the original cut or the SE?

Comment: It is original, from 1977 (Project 4K77)

Comment: I have the "original theatrical release" version - at least the one that was released along with one of the munged-up versions in 2006 as a "bonus feature".  The scene in this version looks just like what is in this answer.